# Расположение картинок как на изображении по типу masonry

Tags: html, css, изображения, flexbox, masonry

У меня есть картинки, завернутые в контейнер. И мне нужно расположить так, как показано на вложенном в вопросе изображении. Это что-то типа mansory. Сам плагин использовать запрещается. Пробовал множества вариантов и Интернета, но безуспешно. Есть у кого какие идеи? Может у кого есть подобная верстка? Помогите пожалуйста! Буду очень признателен. Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

html:

```
<div class="photogallery">
                <img src="img1.jpg">
                <img src="img2.jpg">
                <img src="img3.jpg">
                <img src="img4.jpg">
                <img src="img5.jpg">
                <img src="img6.jpg">
                <img src="img7.jpg">
                <img src="img8.jpg">
 </div>
```

css:

```
.photogallery {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.photogallery img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.photogallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.photogallery img {
  display: inline-flex;
  max-width: 33.33%;
}
.photogallery img:nth-child(4) {
  max-width: 20%;
}
.photogallery img:nth-child(5) {
  max-width: 20%;
}
.photogallery img:nth-child(6) {
  max-width: 15%;
}
.photogallery img:nth-child(7) {
  max-width: 30%;
}
.photogallery img:nth-child(8) {
  max-width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="photogallery">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150">
 </div>
```

простой вариант, без адаптива

Comment: адаптив сделаю сам. спасибо за помощь, друг :)